# How to get Google-apps user profile picture URL

Tags: google-apps, google-contacts-api

Its possible to get the google-apps user profile picture using [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#retrieving_photo) and we can  [get the normal google user profile picture URL](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall) but i need to get the google-apps user profile picture URL. Is there any way to get the google-apps user profile picture URL using the consumer key not with the access token.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

That API call should work for Google Apps users also (all Google Apps accoutns are effectively Google Accounts also). Have you tried it? What error did you get?

Comment: but we are using 2-legged oauth.

Comment: I don't see any reason why 2-legged OAuth wouldn't work. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: The API call will work by authenticate the user but what i need is to get the gapps user's profile picture using consumer key but not with the access token. Because we use it in the google-apps marketplace.

Comment: You should add the Contacts API scope to your application manifest: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest#supported_scopes Then you should be able to manage user photos via the Profiles API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#photo_management

Comment: yes, but it wont give the user photo's URL. I need to get the user photo URL.

Comment: Your application will need to get the image via the Profiles API and then serve it to the client via HTTP.